# When would you use jqGrid no_legacy_api = false?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have read [this post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/is-there-any-benefit-to-disable-legacy-api) about the reason why you would set jqGrid's no_legacy_api property to true. I kind of get his answer. So my question now is when and why would you set (or leave  the value of) that property to false?

I had a look at the code. With my limited know-how on jQuery's function to extend a javascript object, it appears to me that if no_legacy_api is false, jqGrid's extend() will extend both jqGrid and jQuery. Is that correct? If so, why would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find two examples of usage jqGrid [methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods):

1. `$("#grid_id").jqGridMethodName(parameter1, ..., parameterN);`
2. `$("#grid_id").jqGrid("jqGridMethodName", parameter1, ..., parameterN);`

jqGrid is jQuery plugin. So it extends the list of methods which exists on jQuery objects (like on the object `$("#grid_id")`). The problem can exist if you use **many plugins** on one page. If two plugins uses the same name (`getInd` or `clearBeforeUnload` for example) the you will have name conflicts and the last inserted Javascrpt plugin will overwrite some methods of previous one.

Setting the option

```
$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
```

allows you to change the behavior of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (`jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) so that the number of jQuery extensions will be reduced to the minimum. jqGrid register first the method `$.jgrid.extend` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L750-L755)) which it used later to register the most jqGrid methods (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2938) for example).

The correct usage of `no_legacy_api` is the following

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

So you includes `jquery` first, then set `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api` to `true` and finally you includes `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. Later in your code you can use constructs like `var selRow = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");` but can't more use `var selRow = $("#list").getGridParam("selrow");`

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your answer. But I'm not sure you responded to my question. I guess my question is why would jqGrid allow usage of the two ways of calling its functions within the same page/app. (It is allowing this if you set no_legacy_api to false). That seems to encourage bad practise IMHO. I think it should simply allow one or the other--and allow the first/old way of calling functions when you set no_legacy_api to false.

Comment: @FrankFajardo: I explained you how `jgrid.no_legacy_api` **is implemented** in jqGrid. New style API is used internally in all jqGrid code. I personally use only new style API in my demos. The usage of legacy API is dangerous because of possible name conflicts. I don't see any advantage of prohibiting new APIs with default `no_legacy_api = true` setting. If you still think that it's a bug then you should post the bug report to trirand. I don't believe that  the changes which you want will be ever implemented in jqGrid because it requires changing of a lot of existing code which use jqGrid.

Comment: @FrankFajardo: Short described: the prohibition of new style (your interpretation of `no_legacy_api = false`) makes incorrect all internal calls of jqGrid because it uses new API style.

Comment: now that explained it to me. That is really interesting. I learned something new (to me). Thanks